# Apache Geode cache overflow configuration with Persistent data

Tags: caching, geode

I have a PERSISTENT cache configured like this :-

```
<region name="stock-hist" refid="PARTITION_PERSISTENT" >
  <region-attributes disk-store-name="myOverflowStore" disk-   synchronous="false">
<partition-attributes local-max-memory="1024" />
<eviction-attributes>
  <!-- Overflow to disk when 100 megabytes of data reside in the
       region -->
  <lru-memory-size maximum="100" action="overflow-to-disk"/>
</eviction-attributes>
</region-attributes>
```

The problem is that when I storing say 8 GB of data the cache crashes due to too much memory. I do not want that to happen. Like I need the data to overflow to disk when it is beyond 100MB, but get it back to cache if I try to access it. I also want persistent cache.

Also in case I write behind to a database, how can I evict data after sometime.

How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a use-case for which an In-Memory Data Grid is not intended.  Based on the problem that you are describing, you should consider using a relational DB OR you should increase memory to use an *IN-MEMORY* Data Grid.  Overflow features are intended as a safety valve and not for "normal" use.

I do not understand when you say that "it" crashes due to "too much" memory since it obviously does not have "enough" memory. I suspect that there is not have sufficient disk space defined.  If you think not, check your explicit and not implicit disk allocations.

As for time-based eviction/ expiration, please see "PARTITION_HEAP_LRU" at: http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/reference/topics/region_shortcuts_reference.html

Comment: I think Geode allows data to be persisted. So I am trying to use that, what i wanted was that data to be persisted to disk after lets say 1GB of memory was used. This something not possible for Database. I am not sure you understood my problem , however you use partition_persistent_overflow to get that feature. I got it working